# Does Google treat pages on same domain but on different ports as part of same site?

Tags: seo, tomcat

My main website uses port 80/8080 (Apache with Tomcat). But running on the same server I run my own Atlassian JIRA bugtracker, Atlassian requires this to run in its own Apache tomcat server I cannot just deploy another application to the existing tomcat server so have to serve these pages on the 8081 port.

So there are no duplicate pages I just want to know if Google (and other search engines) would consider these as a single site or two sites.

Comment: Good question. I would have to think on that one for a bit. The URL is **not** the same since the URL includes the *:port* so I would assume immediately that they would be two different sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. First of all, if you really care about SEO you should probably not run sites on non-standard ports. I couldn't find any sources for this case specifically but in general Google cares also about user-friendly URLs. I don't think having an extra `:8081` counts as such.

I found [Doorways on Non-default Ports — New Trend in Black Hat SEO?](http://blog.unmaskparasites.com/2010/12/03/doorways-on-non-default-ports-new-trend-in-black-hat-seo/) from late 2010. I guess that Google has also picked up on this by now and is probably a bit more suspicious with websites served on non-standard ports.

Overall, you probably want to set up a virtual host on `jira.example.com:80` that serves stuff from `localhost:8081`.